# problems with grub_install when installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I have been trying to install ubuntu 20.04 on some computers but when I try to install it from the liveUSB. The error I receive is "error grub-install /dev/nvme0n/ failed".

From what I can tell its set up the partitions but not managed to install the grub, looking online it seems like this can sometimes happen from secure boot but I believe I also disabled it and tried with no success. I did however notice that the partitions it set up aren't precisely /dev/nume0n/ but have a number after them.

My question is what exactly is going on with this problem and how I can resolve it? Furthermore is it possible to manually implement the grub-install if there is some typo in the automatic installer or are there other commands required to install ubuntu after the grub-install in the liveUSB installer.

Comment: I haven't seen that label for a storage device before. Did you mean to type "/dev/nvme0n/" ? (That is with a V & not a U?)

Comment: probably, I've updated that in the question (had it written down and probably misread my own handwriting)